# Node.js Sequelize.js Categories.forEach is not a Function

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

This is my function for redirecting to the Add-product when i **res.json(categories)** **it show me the values in CATEGORIES TABLE which i have inserted in db manually by mysql** When its redirected to add_product then it givings me the error Categories.forEach is not a Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `.findAll` versus `.find`. `find` returns a single element.  `findAll` returns the collection you are seeking.

Comment: Find returns one item, FindAll returns a list.